# AWS EC2 instance with ELB for RAILS server SSL works but fail social login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, devise, omniauth, amazon-elb

I have a project set up on Amazon EC2 instance. I am using classic ELB for using aws ssl. I have configured ELB correctly site is running on https. But after moving to ELB aws ssl, social login (Login with facebook/ Login with Google) starts to crash. I have checked the log. The issue is with callback URL. Now the url is as following:

```
http :// mydomain.com:433/url...
```

where it should be

```
https :// mydomin.com/url...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your production.rb enable the SSL.

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Comment: @wasipeer Did you check the redirect url registered in the google and Facebook account?

Comment: Yes they are with https